# How far Entity framework code first fits in Enterprise

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I need to decide on the usage of Entity framework for a large enterprise application.
I need to decide either on EF data first / Code first.

My main idea is not to mix Data Access with Database. I don't want any tool to generate/update database.  I can design database schema first and can use EF Data first model. The problem with this approach is

Less control over the code generated by the EF and 
Huge configuration

I can use code first approach to solve above problems. But the problem with code fist is tight integration with database and EF. whenever I change my Model I need to create Migrations to update the changes to the DB. I am little worried with the changes "Migrations" will make to my DB. moreover If we have to apply these changes to Production DB its not at all possible as we development team won't have any access to production servers.

I am just thinking weather it is a good choice to choose EF code first as data access technology for an Enterprise application.

Can you guys suggest usage of EF code first without above problems?

Comment: You can use code first without migrations (with existing database). You can even work without any generated code in all EF approaches. It is only up to you how much work do you want to do yourselves (writing all classes, mappings, etc.)

Comment: @LadislavMrnka, so back to the question, if I'm about to create a new enterprise project with a DB for millions of records, is code-first (generated DB) a bad idea? Does Code-First support views, sprocs UDFs etc.?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would strongly recommend against Code First for a large enterprise level application.

Enterprise Level Applications normally have

- API Projects
- Multi-web applications / interfaces
- Synchronization with other data sources
- Specific optimizations with large datasets.
- DBA's are involved
- Large databases start getting Sharded
- Multi-Continent Deployments
- SQL Level Security Requirements and Logging
- and more ...

Data First allows you to take all of this into consideration and not have a database bound by a project.

Code First is great when you have single use applications such as tablet apps or desktop apps or even just for doing quick development. When multiple projects need to access the same database, I would say Code First is no longer suitable.

Comment: Your opinion is interesting, but I would be more interested in the reasons why you think so. None of the points about what enterprise apps usually have directly explain why code first is not a good approach, nor do I understand why code first should lead to sharded databases, but database first would not? In either approach, you can override the conventions that decide how the actual O/R-mapping is done, and how the LINQ queries get translated to SQL surely depends on the O/R-mapping, not the workflow used to define the O/R-mapping.

Comment: The main point I am trying to make is that in an enterprise scenario a single app is unlikely to be the only application using that database. If your app is the only one that uses that db, then there would be no issues with code first. If it's not, then the database needs to lead the design because your app is not the driving force in its design, only a part of it.